# PostgreSQL: return message after count = 0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have maybe easy question, but I'm completely stucked.

I have script

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(id), 0) as MyFiels from table
```

It works fine and when I have zero value it shows 0.

But I want that instead of 0, I can see one line = "NO RESULTS" for example.

I tried:

```
SELECT COALESCE(to_char(COUNT(id), 'NO RESULT')) as MyFiels from table
```

And PostgreSQL shows error message:

```
ERROR: "E" is not supported
SQL state: 0A000
```

Where I'm incorrect? Any ideas?

Comment: well you are trying to make a column return `INT` and return `TEXT`

Comment: Yes, I want to convert int to text and show message

Comment: Also try closing the parenthesis on the right position `to_char(COUNT(id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is the error, you are trying to use coalesce to convert 0 to string, and coalesce convert null to something. You need use a CASE

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*)  = 0 THEN 'NO RESULT'
             ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) as TEXT)
        END as field
FROM Table
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. It really works, I spent a lot of time of trying to do this task.