# SELECT CASE: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I got very good help for my question [PostgreSQL: return message after count = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771537/postgresql-return-message-after-count-0)

This query works fine:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*)  = 0 THEN 'NO RESULT'
            ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) as TEXT)
        END as myfield from mytable
```

But today I need if some rows are in table, I need to show select result.

I tried:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*)  = 0 THEN 'NO RESULT'
             ELSE (select name from mytable)
        END as myfield from mytable
```

And I got error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I found that `IN` function but don't have any idea to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
select name from mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO RESULT'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM mytable)
```